# Javascript canvas animation stopped working with control keys

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

First, I have made an animation

```
http://jsfiddle.net/hS2uF/
```

Now, I have been trying to implement this animation into control keys for hours, but still I can't figure out what's wrong :/? (It allows me to control the object though..)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/7cua6/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You're calling init twice, so you're actually running two animation loops that immediately override each other.

Comment: so how do i actually need to do to make it work :/?

Comment: could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following lines

```
imgBackground.addEventListener('load', drawBg, false); // init to drawBg
```

and

```
function init(){
//drawBg(); remove this as you already calling on load of image
loop();
document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp, false);  
}
```

Now the animation WORKS BUT you are using requestAnimationFrame which run 60fps so you are not able to see the animation properly. So if you want to use requestAnimationFrame then you need to have more sprites.

If you cannot provide more sprites then do not use requestAnimationFrame instead use setTimeout (which is not recommended though) and make use of 10fps which you have used in your first example.

## Update :

Here is the fiddle which gives your animation working
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/7cua6/3/)

## More Update:

for better fps on moving the tadpole change this

```
Player.prototype.checkDirection = function(){
if(this.isUpKey){
    this.drawY -= this.speed*this.width/10; // using width of the tadpole and 10fps
}
if(this.isRightKey){
    this.drawX += this.speed*this.width/10;
}
if(this.isDownKey){
    this.drawY += this.speed*this.width/10;
}
if(this.isLeftKey){
    this.drawX -= this.speed*this.width/10;
}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/7cua6/5/)  for that

Comment: Thanks but I have few questions. First how does that line affect the animation? also, how do I add the setTimeout without affecting the controlling fps?

Comment: can you please tell me which line? for setTimeout you need to take out requestAnimationFrame and use setTimeout

Comment: added fiddle please check it

Comment: This line: `imgBackground.addEventListener('load', drawBg, false); // init to drawBg
` It looks like this now http://jsfiddle.net/Cp9BZ/

Comment: I can't see your fiddle ( I don't think you can edit my file:/?)

Comment: that line effects because when you call init two times and you are not even able to see the animation. when you call init only once you can see the animation but too fast for our naked eye.

Comment: you cant see my fiddle.!!!!!!!! here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/7cua6/3/ by the way i have forked your fiddle so i can edit in my scope. its not yours its mine. :P

Comment: I see, but when I press up,down,left,right arrow keys it is so slow, it's like the same fps as the animation?

Comment: my example is not using requestAnimationFrame. I am using setTimeout with 10fps as your first example. for moving animation you need to change the checkDirection method. see this fiddle with better fps for moving http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/7cua6/5/ updated answer with description

Comment: is there anyway to make it smoother :/? and using requestAnimationFrame at the same time. maybe 2 requestAnimationFrame? I don't know :/

Comment: AFAIK you need to have more sprites for the tadpole. to have smoother animation and using requestAnimationFrame

Comment: don't worry I finally figured it out!!! I added a function `function animation(){
 setTimeout(function(){
 requestAnimationFrame(animation); 
 if (player.currentFrame == player.frames) {
  player.currentFrame = 0;
 } else {
  player.currentFrame++;
 }
 }, 1000 / 15);
}` and put it under `function loop()` and Thanks for the help I greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: that great you solved. can you please provide the updated fiddle